# How to restrict possible value of index type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

We can declare `index signature` to force the properties of object to be of specific type such as below

```js
const LOOKUP: {
  [key: string]: { name: string, age: number };
} = {
  isaac: { name: 'isaac', age: 20 },
  whatever: {name: 'whatever', age: 17}
};
```

However, I would like to restrict the possible values that goes as `key`, so below is my attempt

**Attempt 1**

```js
type PossibleName = 'isaac' | 'john';

const LOOKUP: {
  [key: PossibleName]: { name: string, age: number };
} = {
  isaac: { name: 'isaac', age: 20 },
  whatever: {name: 'whatever', age: 17}
};
```

The attempt above hitting error below

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

**Attempt 2**

```js
type PossibleName = 'isaac' | 'john';

const LOOKUP: {
  [key in PossibleName]: { name: string, age: number };
} = {
  isaac: { name: 'isaac', age: 20 },
};
```

And attempt 2 is hitting error below

> Property 'john' is missing in type '{ isaac: { name: string; age: number; }; }' but required in type '{ isaac: { name: string; age: number; }; john: { name: string; age: number; }; }'

I can solve it by making the key optional such as below

```js
type PossibleName = 'isaac' | 'john';

const LOOKUP: {
  [key in PossibleName]?: { name: string, age: number };
} = {
  isaac: undefined,
};
```

It does allow to not declare `john`, but at the same time allowing value `undefined` for both `isaac` & `john`, which is not what I wanted.

My goal is that if I defined `isaac`, or `john`, the value should not be accepting `undefined`, but has to be of type `{ name: string, age: number}`, wondering if that's possible?

Comment: *"which is not what I wanted"* So what do you want?

Comment: @FelixKling: My idea is that, if I defined `Isaac`, or `john`, the value should not be accepting `undefined`, but has to be of type `{ name: string, age: number}`, wondering if that's possible?

Comment: From a practical runtime perspective, there is no difference between `{}` and `john: undefined`). Making something optional is the same as allowing its value to be `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling: agreed, however from code maintainability wise, i would like to throw error to developer if they ever assign `undefined` to the props, as `undefined` is a valid value. Exactly why i felt `[key in PossibleName]?` sounds weird coz I don't really wanna make it optional, but to restrict the possible values

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that with TS (have an optional property and not allow it to be `undefined`). Even in JavaScript the lines get blurry, because in function calls `undefined` is treated as "empty" argument (e.g. `function foo(v='hello') { console.log(v); }` will log `'hello'` if called with `foo()` or `foo(undefined)`.

Comment: So what you want is something like `{john: Person} | {isaac: Person}`? Or `{john: Person} | {isaac: Person} | {john: Person, isaac: Person}`?

Comment: @FelixKling: To be exact `{john: Person} | {isaac: Person}| {isaac: Person; john: Person}`. But this gets really messy if we have more possible values, wondering if you have better options?

Comment: Maybe use an array instead (if you want to allow multiple objects)? `{name: PossibleName, age: number}[]`

Comment: @FelixKling: Not possible, `LOOKUP` is an object, we are just trying to typed it to add restriction

Answer (score 1):

```
type PossibleName = 'isaac' | 'john';
type Person = { name: string }
type MyType = {
  [K in PossibleName]: { [k in K]: Person }
}[PossibleName] | { [K in PossibleName]: Person }
```

Not pretty, just find a way to abuse TS engine. This will yield `{john: Person} | {isaac: Person}| {isaac: Person; john: Person}`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIDkCGBbaAXigHJkEccBjEqAH1ICs4ALAOxIG4AoUSWCACcEcNlGIBvKG3wQAXFATBByNgHMoAX17hoAWRAAVXeKgTuUKAG0A0lFWxEKDNlkBdBVKsBre2JseAsKiWtyaVvBIaJi4BG70ZtZ2DpHOMe4KMEIiYppAA)

Comment: It will still be possible to pass undefined values though https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIDkCGBbaAXigHJkEccBjEqAH1ICs4ALAOxIG4AoUSWCACcEcNlGIBvKG3wQAXFATBByNgHMoAX17hoAWRAAVXeKgTuUKAG0A0lFWxEKDNlkBdBVKsBre2JseAsKiWtyaVvBIaJi4BG70ZtZ2DpHOMe4KMEIiYtrcVKJKUABmcHAKBsb8kuSUVJ4yBAoARM2aADRQzOwKAK5sACYQxaoQA5pAA

Comment: That’s unexpected  I don’t understand what happened.